# Changing permissions and setting up paths

Tags: 14.04

I would like to know is there a way to change to change priorities for folders in /usr/share directory, so that we can work with it a with ordinary folder? I have texlive, and it is very annoying using super user mode to work with it. I've tried searching for solution, but nothing worked.

Also I know that program can not remember anything by itself, and it has to make a file, to write to it new parameters, so it can use them instead of default, so I like to know location of the file, where paths are written.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *change priorities for folders in /usr/share directory*?

Comment: Use the folder as ordinary one, in user mode, as all other folders in home directory.

Comment: You shouldn't want that (and you don't, really), permissions are set for a good reason.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a copy of a file you want to edit, change the permissions on the copy and work with that in texlive. Then copy it back to the proper location with the proper permissions once you've finished working on it?

Comment: I know that permissions are for a reason, but texlive is ordinary probgram and only reason it is in /usr/share, because its installed from package meneger, and some parts should be corrected manually

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean permissions for a file instead of priorities??

If you are the only user on your system changing permission should be safe. But it's usually a better idea to use your home folder for the files you are working on. So, you can copy those files in your home folder.

Comment: Really, *If you are the only user on your system changing permission should be safe??* In `/usr/share`?

Comment: not exactly....consider you are running a application in your system and that application has some bugs or it was malicious application...now that running applications will have access rights to change that file and it can modify it without your will...there are some reason  that some files aren't in home directory and you don't have write permission on them!!